# GPIO control in Python for Orange Pi 3 Lts

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpio, orange-pi

I wanted to use the pull-up and pull-down resistances on Orange Pi 3 Lts board in Python 3 environment.

However, I am struggling to actually change the pins from high to low and vice versa.

I am using some push buttons, so I need to use the pin's internal resistance. I don't want to use external resistances.

Thanks.

I have already tried Wiring OP (which gives you the state of the pins) and some git hub repositories given below but still, I am usually getting errors like "segmentation fault" etc.

```
https://github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3
https://github.com/lanefu/WiringPi-Python-OP
https://pypi.org/project/pyA20/0.2.12/
https://github.com/orangepi-xunlong/wiringOP-Python
https://github.com/xpertsavenue/WiringOP-Zero-Python
https://pypi.org/project/wiringpi/
```

Comment: Does it run Linux? If so, use `libgpiod` for that. It has Python bindings.